# Attempting to check out an SVN repository over VPN

Tags: linux, vpn, svn

Folks,

I have connected to the company VPN which is a PPTP setup. I seem to be successfully connected, but when I do this:

svn checkout http://192.168.0.4/svn/main/projects/KT01/software/dev/KT01SW02

Although it populates the target directory on the local machine with the directory structure of the repository it will not download any source code.

I can navigate through the repository just fine with a web browser.

Local machine is Linux running Mageia 6 and work is a Windows setup.

Anyone have any ideas what the problem might be? I will supply any information necessary to solve this, but at the moment I do not know what else would be useful.

Many thanks.

Comment: Try: `svn update --depth infinity`

Comment: Well that didn't work, then I noticed it had disconnected, so I tried it again and it did it. Thanks!

Comment: Good. So I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have run into the problem of
[Sparse Directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html)
defined as:

> By default, most Subversion operations on directories act in a recursive manner. For example, svn checkout creates a working copy with every file and directory in the specified area of the repository, descending recursively through the repository tree until the entire structure is copied to your local disk. Subversion 1.5 introduces a feature called *sparse directories* (or *shallow checkouts*) that allows you to easily check out a working copy—or a portion of a working copy—**more shallowly than full recursion**, with the freedom to bring in previously ignored files and subdirectories at a later time.

To complete the checkout, use the command:

```
svn update --depth infinity
```

The `--depth infinity` parameter can also be added to the `svn checkout` command
for a complete checkout.